# add values using the first cell as index

Tags: excel, indexing

I have 3 columns

```
    A   B   C
1   ABC 5   1
2   CDE 6   3
3   CDE 7   3
4   ABC 8   4
5   FGH 9   5
6   GFH 1   6
7   FGH 2   7
8   GFE 3   8
9   ABC 4   9
```

How do I sum up the values for column B and C for the cells that contain ABC. Because ABC is on row number 1, 4, and 9. But how do I use this when I have plenty of rows.

Comment: first, switch of the capslock. Second, what have you tried so far? We dont write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A9="ABC")*(B1:B9))+SUMPRODUCT((A1:A9="ABC")*(C1:C9))
```

[image]